# navigate textview of gridview with arrows android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have an application that will be used on a large screen and operated only with an external keyboard. There is a gridview dynamically inflated according to a database and I have to scroll through its items with the arrows on the external keyboard and highlight the one that has the focus so that if the Enter key is pressed an alertdialog is displayed with the data of that item. I can show the alert with the data, but I don't know how to navigate the gridview with the arrows on an external keyboard.

change the selection focus of each element of the gridview and show alert with data of the selected element when pressing ENTER

Comment: welcome , Plz read [HOW TO ASK](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to go through the recyclerview items and get the position in an alertdialog